# Using service in the constructor of a MODEL (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, model

So,
My goal is to use service in a model constructor because my service use info and method that my constructor could use.

For better understanding, i immagined a user case on the fly.
Don't forget it's just an exemple for the problem.

## Models

Let's say i've a model with dog info
But also,
I want the height difference with the breed average.

```
Class Dog{

id: string;
name: string
breed: string
age: number
height: number
dif_Height: number

Constructor(id, name, breed, age, height){

this.id = id;
this.name = name,
this.breed= breed,
this.age = age,
this.height = height

}
}
```

## Services

By change, in my service, i've a perfect function for it

In my service, all the breed info are stored.
And i've function that give me the Height Diff by sending the breed.

```
 GetbreedDif(breed){

// FIND MY BREED

// CALCUL THE DIF

// 

return  HeightDif;
}
```

Now, I want to use this specific function in MY MODELS.

What his the best way to implement it ?

## My ideas

*- I send the service as parameter*

```
Constructor(id, name, breed, age, height, service){

this.id = id;
this.name = name,
this.breed = breed,
this.age = age,
this.height = height,
this.dif_Height = service.GetbreedDif(breed)

}
```

But I don't like to send my service this way, and think this is'nt optimal.

*- I Recreate the function, using my service info as parameter*

```
Constructor(id, name, breed, age, height, service_breedlist){

this.id = id;
this.name = name,
this.breed = breed,
this.age = age,
this.height = height,
this.dif_Height = this.GetbreedDif(breed, service_breedlist)

}
```

```
GetbreedDif(breed, MyServiceList){

// FIND MY BREED

// CALCUL THE DIF

// 

return  HeightDif;
}
```

Which i found better, but pretty annoying to pass something that is already fixed somehere else, especially if, for some reasons i must create a lot of object.

*- Inject the service in the models ?*

It's my third idea.
But, i'm not sure of the exact implementation and also of the consequence of it.

*- Something else ?*

Is there any method i did'nt think about and would be good ?

Comment: you can have a factory service, which would inject any other services and it would create model however you want

Answer (score 0):

If your service method does not have a state, then using a static method might be the solution here.

```js
// service
export class BreedDiffService {
   static GetBreedDiff(breed) {
       // do work here
   }
}

// model constructor
constructor(id, name, breed, age, height, service){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name,
    this.breed = breed,
    this.age = age,
    this.height = height,
    this.difHeight = BreedDiffService.GetBreedDiff(breed)
}
```

Please note that this isn't using an instance of the service but instead calling the method directly through the class. I also haven't tested this but this should probably work.